# Scrabble word combination from rack in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example if I have 'QOFTHEA' in rack, I would like to create every possible combination of words length from 2 to 7 to compare them with another source of word list. How should I create it in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use use `itertools.permutations` and `itertools.chain.from_iterable`:

```
from itertools import chain, permutations

rack = 'QOFTHEA'

lo, hi = 2, 7

for perm in chain.from_iterable(permutations(rack, i) for i in range(lo, hi + 1)):
    print(perm)
```

If you wanted a string instead of a tuple of characters, you can do `''.join(perm)`.

Comment: Thanks. Is it another way to do it using for loop or so? :)

Comment: @aquantum You could, but it's pointless to complicate it like so. `itertools` is built into Python, so there's really no reason to not use the tools it offers.

Comment: I just wanna know how it works. I tried to create with for loop, but couldn’t do it.

Comment: Shouldn't it be combinations instead of permutations, since that's requested by the OP

Comment: @kerwei OP said combination, but I'm assuming they are not using it in the technical sense of combinatorics. They said they are comparing it with a word list, so permutations is more correct.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking all the permutations (`5912` for 7 letter is fine but `4 037 912` possibilities for 10 letters is uncomputable) against a long list. I would suggest checking the list against the letters (the complexity now depends from the length of the list which is by definition shorter than all the permutations). This allows you to not load the whole dictionary in memory as it can be quite large :

```
from collections import Counter
rack = Counter('QOFTHEA')
with open('words.txt') as f:
    for word in (i[:-1] for i in f):
        if len(word) > len(rack):
            continue
        word_counter = Counter(word)
        for l, c in word_counter.items():
            if l not in rack:
                break
            else:
                if c > rack[l]:
                    break
        else:
            print(word)
```

If for some reason you don't want to use the standard library:

```
def Counter(iterable):
    dic = {}
    for i in iterable:
        if i not in dic:
            dic[i] = 1
        dic[i] += 1
    return dic
```

Good scrabbling !